# After pushing hook useHistory I get ' Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by ...'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am in a page localhost:8080/authors/1

I do a post and as I post I get a new id 2.
With this new id I want to jump to the page localhost:8080/authors/2 from localhost:8080/authors/1.

in AuthorForm:

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
const history = useHistory()
const onSubmit = async data => {
    const response = await onUpdateData({author: data});
    history.push(`/authors/${response?.data?.createAuthor?.id}`);
  }
```

on localhost:8080/authors/:id I use useParams() to get the id

```
    const authorId = useParams()?.id;    
          const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(fetchAuthor, {
                variables: {id: authorId} })
                if(loading) {
                  return(<div> Loading </div>)
                }
                if(error) {
                  return(<div> error </div>)
                }
                  return (<AuthorForm initialValues={formTranslator(data)}/>);
        
            }
```

After pushing hook useHistory  I get 'react_devtools_backend.js:2430 Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by 'x'. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add skip to useQuery

Answer (score 0):

I found hard to work with apollo useQuery.
Using ApolloClient instead and useEffects the issues disappeared, from now on I will be very careful when working with useQuery.